# Is there an algorithm or shortcut for continually updating and summing sub-sections of arrays?

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, arrays

Let's say I have an NxN array if integers. I want to continually update it, but also continually query for the sum of an arbitrary sub-section. So example would be as follows:

We start with a 3x3 array of all 0s.

Operations:

> update 1,1 to 3
>
> update 1,2 to 1
>
> update 0,0 to 2
>
> update 2,2 to 6
>
> print sub-section starting at 1,1 going to 2,2 (should print 10)
>
> more updates...
>
> more queries...

The array looks like this at the time of first query:

```
2 0 0
0 3 0
0 1 6
```

I want to do this for much larger arrays, and much more queries in a reasonable amount of time. I believe less than O(N^2) per query is possible. Any ideas?

EDIT: I'm asking this because Hackerrank has several of these types of questions and I was banging my head against a wall trying to come up with a strategy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data structures you're looking for are [quad trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree) (for linear time queries, logarithmic time updates, quadratic space) or the more complicated [2d interval trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree) (for logarithmic time queries, logarithmic time updates, $O(N^2 \log N)$ space).

I suspect you are trying to solve competitive programming problem, if so please state it in your question.

Comment: Yes, HackerRank has an increasing number of these types of questions. I was trying to use memoization and failing spectacularly. I'll edit my original question to say it is from HackerRank.